# Getting a value from HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() in Tomcat without modifying application

Tags: java, tomcat, basic-authentication

(Using Java 6 and Tomcat 6.)

Is there a way for me to get `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` to return a value in my development environment (i.e. localhost) without needing to modify my application's web.xml file?

The reason I ask is that the authentication implementation when the app is deployed to a remote environment is handled by a web server and plugged-in tool. Running locally I obviously do not have the plugged-in tool or a separate web server; I just have Tomcat 6. I am trying to avoid adding code to my application merely to support development on my localhost.

I am hoping there is a modification I can make to the context.xml or server.xml files that will let me set the remote user ID or that will try to pull it from a HTTP header or something.

Comment: How your webapp communicate with this plugin?

Comment: @palacsint The web app doesn't communicate with the plug-in; the web server looks after it. The web app just asks the `HttpServletRequest` instance for the remote user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept `Valve` implementation which does it:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.realm.GenericPrincipal;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;

public class RemoteUserValve extends ValveBase {

    public RemoteUserValve() {
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(final Request request, final Response response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String username = "myUser";
        final String credentials = "credentials";
        final List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Tomcat 7 version
        final Principal principal = new GenericPrincipal(username, 
                            credentials, roles);
            // Tomcat 6 version:
            // final Principal principal = new GenericPrincipal(null, 
            //              username, credentials, roles);


        request.setUserPrincipal(principal);

        getNext().invoke(request, response);
    }

}
```

(Tested with Tomcat 7.0.21.)

Compile it, put it inside a jar and copy the jar to the `apache-tomcat-7.0.21/lib` folder. You need to modify the `server.xml`:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Valve className="remoteuservalve.RemoteUserValve" />
...
```

I suppose it works inside the `Engine` and `Context` containers too.

More information:

- [The Valve Component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html)
- [Valve javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the information! I created a class like you describe, JAR'd it up and updated the `server.xml` file. I had to make one change because I am running Tomcat v6.0.20: the `GenericPrincipal` signature requires a realm so I added `final Realm realm = request.getContext().getRealm();`. However, it doesn't seem to be having an effect. I've tried updating the `context.xml` file, too, but again it produced no result. The request's principal and user ID are both `null` when they reach my application code. Did you perhaps do anything else?

Comment: I just passed `null` as realm, and it works for me with Tomcat 6.0.20. (See my modifications in the answer.) Are there any exception in your logs?

Comment: Thanks very much for the help with all this. It turns out I had your valve implemented correctly all along. The reason it didn't work was because I wasn't savvy to the significance of setting the `catalina.base` JVM property on server start-up. Once I altered the `server.xml` at that location it all worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually you can forget the `GenericPrincipal` and implement the simple `Principal` interface yourself or rip off [`BasicUserPrincipal`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/auth/BasicUserPrincipal.java) from Apache HttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

Use a local, file-based realm for testing. Check your `conf/tomcat-users.xml` and create roles and users for your application and enable the security constraints in your web.xml. There are good examples in the `tomcat-users.xml`.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed the `tomcat-users.xml` file and know about adding security constraints within my app's web.xml, but I am asking if there is a way to achieve something similar _without_ modifying actual/real/destined-for-production code; I would be happier modifying just my local server configuration.

Comment: Hi, palacsint Could you show more details of deployed the remote user through xml file... Thanks!

Comment: @Edward: I'm sorry, I don't have time now for a complete answer. I guess you should ask it as a new question. Drop me a link and I'll check on the weekend if nobody answer it.

Comment: Thank you very much! palacsint, I have posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519596/request-getremoteuser-returns-null), Thanks ...