# Tomcat : Bypass basic Authentication for Specified IP Address

Tags: tomcat

I have configured tomcat for basic authentication.
I do not want anyone to have access to my web application but the app is serving web services.
So I want to bypass a specific ip address from basic authentication.( that ip should not require authentication.)

tomcat-users.xml :

```
<tomcat-users>
<user username="user" password="password" roles="user"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

web.xml :

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>user</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>


<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>You must enter your login credentials to continue</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
   <description>
      The role that is required to log in to the Application
   </description>
   <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Thanks,
Chetan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you would like to allow just only a few IP addresses and disallow everybody else the [Remote Address Filter Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter) is what you need.

If you want that the clients from unknown IP addresses see the basic login dialog and could login you need a custom [`Valve`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html). The source of the [`RemoteAddrValve`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat/catalina/7.0.39.2/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteAddrValve.java/) (and it's parent class [`RequestFilterValve`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat/catalina/7.0.39.2/org/apache/catalina/valves/RequestFilterValve.java#RequestFilterValve) is a good starting point. Take a look [my former answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553967/getting-a-value-from-httpservletrequest-getremoteuser-in-tomcat-without-modifyi/7560802#7560802).

Anyway, below is a proof of concept code. It puts a filled `Principal` to the `Request` if the client is coming from a trusted IP so the login module will not ask for the password. Otherwise it does not touch the `Request` object and the user can log in as usual.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.realm.GenericPrincipal;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;

public class AutoLoginValve extends ValveBase {

    private String trustedIpAddress;

    public AutoLoginValve() {
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(final Request request, final Response response) 
             throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
        final boolean isTrustedIp = remoteAddr.equals(trustedIpAddress);
        System.out.println("remoteAddr: " + remoteAddr + ", trusted ip: " 
                + trustedIpAddress + ", isTrustedIp: " + isTrustedIp);
        if (isTrustedIp) {
            final String username = "myTrusedUser";
            final String credentials = "credentials";
            final List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
            roles.add("user");
            roles.add("admin");

            final Principal principal = new GenericPrincipal(username, 
                credentials, roles);
            request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
        }

        getNext().invoke(request, response);
    }

    public void setTrustedIpAddress(final String trustedIpAddress) {
        System.out.println("setTrusedIpAddress " + trustedIpAddress);
        this.trustedIpAddress = trustedIpAddress;
    }

}
```

And a config example for the `server.xml`:

```
<Valve className="autologinvalve.AutoLoginValve" 
    trustedIpAddress="127.0.0.1" />
```

Comment: Thank you palacsinit, I'll try to add this and will post results soon.