# Bypass Basic authentication to solr from my website with tomcat

Tags: java, security, tomcat, solr

I have my website which is in the same server than sorl.
I would like that solr will allow queries just from my website, and not from external ips, of course for security reasons.
So then my webpage will be the only one which can do queries like:

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/select/?q=*:*&wt=json&json.wrf=?&indent=true", function(result){}
```

but since i have my sorl application with configured with auth its always prompting to write the username and password.

```
    <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Solr Lockdown</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>solr_admin</role-name>
     <role-name>admin</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
   <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   <realm-name>Solr</realm-name>
 </login-config>
```

i checked in here, but this solution its blocking also my main website and is still prompting the password when i do query
[Tomcat : Bypass basic Authentication for Specified IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631974/tomcat-bypass-basic-authentication-for-specified-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you are making a JSON call from the client browser, not the web server. In this scenario all calls to Solr will originate from the client machines. You will need to have your web server make the call to Solr and expose that via a url in your website that the JSON call can execute.

Also, if you restrict by IP Address, you need to remove the basic authentication or both will be applied.

Comment: So then what it will be an easy solution to be able to request queries to solr just from my website?

Comment: As I stated in the answer, you will need to make calls to Solr directly from your web application. Based on the language that your web application is executing, there are some Solr Clients that you could select from - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr

Comment: There are some parts where i am usign already SolrJ, my idea it was to do it some of the queries by Ajax, and in that way "save" the memory i would have spend for the JVM, doing all the process of parsing and so on.