# How do I set the remote user in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, basic-authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a value from HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() in Tomcat without modifying application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553967/getting-a-value-from-httpservletrequest-getremoteuser-in-tomcat-without-modify)

Short version: How can I configure Tomcat to use a specific name (say, `"johndoe"`) as the remote user name?

The details: I'm working on a Java web application that will be deployed to production using Tomcat.  The production server is configured to prompt the user for authentication before they ever reach this application, so the app will only need to use something like the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` method `getRemoteUser()` to get the user's name.  This works very well, in fact.  It's already been tested.

The problem is that it's not practical (for various reasons) to install this authentication process on my development machine.  I'd also like to avoid adding special-purpose code in the application just to accommodate my local testing.  I thought that it would be best if I could just force the username I want to test with into Tomcat's configuration.  Then the `getRemoteUser()` would return `"johndoe"` every time.  Of course, in production, that username wouldn't be forced into the environment, the actual authentication process would run instead.

I can't figure out how to configure that username into Tomcat, though.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you add a security contraint in your web.xml on your dev machine which protects all pages/links? Hence when you hit the app in your local environment, you will be presented with a dialog box.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553967/getting-a-value-from-httpservletrequest-getremoteuser-in-tomcat-without-modify

Comment: @UsmanSaleem: Doesn't that mean I would need to deal with a dialog box every time I run the application?  I don't want to have to do that.  I can see that it might be a good way for me to switch to a different user, to test the application using their account, but I don't want an obtrusive solution.

Comment: @palacsint:  Thanks, I'll go look at that solution more closely.  At first glance, I think it will work, but I'm surprised that it's as complex as all that.  I expected the solution to be adding a few tags to one of the Tomcat XML config files.  PS: You should add your comment as an answer to my question.  If you do, I'll give you the checkmark and you'll earn the points.  I'm surprised the question you reference didn't come up when I searched Stack Overflow nor when I started entering my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Getting a value from HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() in Tomcat without modifying application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553967/getting-a-value-from-httpservletrequest-getremoteuser-in-tomcat-without-modify/7560802#7560802) - This answer contains a `Valve` which does exactly this. It works with Tomcat, tested with Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7.

[Getting a value from HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() in Tomcat without modifying application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553967/getting-a-value-from-httpservletrequest-getremoteuser-in-tomcat-without-modify/7554189#7554189) - This another answer also could be useful. It's about a file based realm which also requires some Tomcat server configuration but without any coding.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll give these a try.

Comment: This worked out great.  I have a question, though.  Do you think it's possible to pass parameters from server.xml to the RemoteUserValve?  For example, I imagine something like: <Valve className="remoteuservalve.RemoteUserValve"><Parameter key="name" value="myUser"></Valve>

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You just need a setter method. Check the source of any existing `Valve`, for example [AccessLogVale](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.java.html#411). You can find a sample usage in the default `server.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the great pointers.  I've implemented the valve for my development environment so that it will use the "user.name" system property for the user name it will return unless a "name" attribute is specified in the server.xml.  Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing on top of my head is to implement your own [Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html) and modify the request at runtime to add the user name that you want for the authentication.

You will use this `Valve` only in your development environment for your testing.

Comment: Sorry, what is your point exactly?